# Past run commands still being displayed when opening new terminal

Tags: command-line

[image]

Whenever I open a new terminal 2 lines of Past run code are displayed on the top, and I am able to remove them with reset and clear but it's just for that terminal, if I open another terminal it is being displayed and continues to display whenever I open a new terminal. Please refer the picture for better understanding.

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! Could you please [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1229686/edit) your question with the following information? What version of Ubuntu are you using? What version of `rbenv` is installed, and have you attempted a `purge` and `install` cycle of the software?

Comment: Those likely aren't "past run commands" - they're things in your `~/.bashrc` or similar shell initialization file that are being run again each time you open a new terminal

Answer (score 0):

You need to check if you have any lines that `mkdir` within your `~/.bashrc` file or `~/.profile` file.